# How to speed up the rendering time to display drone-derived orthophoto in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geotiff-tiff, rendering, orthophoto

I have a 4cm resolution drone-derived image GeoTIFF that I am displaying in QGIS. The image is approx 600mb, I have a compressed version (BIGTIFF=YES, TILED=YES) approx 250mb.
Both when loaded into QGIS (3.20) take a very long time to load.

Is there a simple way to speed this up? For example, if I load the KML version (128mb) into Google Earth, it's renders almost immediately.

Answer (score 5):

You need create overviews/pyramids.

You can create them within QGIS in `Layer properties / Pyramids`. Make sure to use external format to avoid messing up your carefully created, already huge TIFF.

That being said, especially with such a huge file, and to have better control over compression of the overview compression etc., it's better to use the command line. See https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html (note GDAL is included under the hood in QGIS).  You'll probably want to pick what overview levels you need and specify a `COMPRESS_OVERVIEW` configuration option.

Comment: BTW make sure you're using a recent version of QGIS, and especially GDAL under the hood. Not sure of the details, but I believe big TIFF support improved in GDAL significantly around v3.1(+-?)